# Can you use a minute plan with Google Voice?

Tags: wi-fi, google-voice

I recently learned about Google Voice and was wondering if I could apply it to my current cellular situation.

I have a pre-paid minute plan with an Android phone. Ideally, I'd like to use minutes whenever I'm not under a Wi-Fi network, and when under a Wi-Fi network texting and talking would be free. Is this possible with Google Voice?

Comment: Am not so sure, but Viber seems an alternative if Google voice is not appropriate for your needs! You are based in the USA/Canada?

Comment: @t0mm13b: Yes, I am in the United States.

Comment: The answer is: Maybe. Certainly the phone number forwarding feature of GV is available to you, but whether or not the Google Voice app will run on your phone or integrate well with the carrier depends on, well, the carrier. Why not just try it? Google Voice is currently free; you have nothing to lose.

Comment: @user1: I have a T-Mobile plan minute plan at the moment with my 7 year old cell phone. The Android phones in my house are not T-Mobile so I cannot use the SIM card.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Google Voice with a non-smart phone, but it will be somewhat limited. If the only device you carry is the dumb phone, you won't be able to do any calling over wifi (obviously).

However, if you carry a wifi android device with you, you can set up Google Voice over wifi using a few methods, such as [GrooveIP](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.gvoip&hl=en), or [SIP Droid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.sipdroid.sipua) with [these setup instructions](http://www.droidxforums.com/forum/droid-x-apps/15366-sipdroid-free-voip-via-google-voice.html).

To only show your Google Voice number to callees when using your non-smart prepaid, follow Option 1 in [this answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/40701/11190). Note that it will cost you 10-15 seconds each time you call someone, as the phone will manually dial the number after calling your own google voice number. Receiving calls won't take up any extra time.

If you don't care about your friends and families having 2 numbers for you, you don't need to do anything different for your prepaid. Just know that if *they* call *you* on your non-GV number, you won't be able to accept it on your wifi android device (it won't ring). You would need to explain that they should only ever call you on your GV number.